# URLClassLoader + loadClass + invoke main method on a standalone process? Java

Tags: java, process, invoke, urlclassloader

I'm using the following method to invoke a class inside a jar file:

```
invokeClass("path.to.classfile", new String[] {});

public static void invokeClass(String name, String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, MalformedURLException {
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + ".myapplication"+File.separator+"myjar.jar");

    URLClassLoader u = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{f.toURI().toURL()});
    Class c = u.loadClass(name);
      Method m = c.getMethod("main", new Class[] { args.getClass() });
      m.setAccessible(true);
      int mods = m.getModifiers();
      if (m.getReturnType() != void.class || !Modifier.isStatic(mods) || !Modifier.isPublic(mods)) {
        throw new NoSuchMethodException("main");
      }
      try {
        m.invoke(null, new Object[] { args });
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

      }
}
```

Is it possible to invoke this on a separate process? So the running application and the new invoked application have nothing in common?

Situation: You launch program a (client updater). From client a you launch program b (client)

With the current code, project a AND all instances of project b share the same heap space. I'm trying to achieve a state where all instances of project b are stand-alone and do not care if project A is terminated or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and actually that saves you from executing that reflection  process altogether

You'll need to use [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to start a new process in a separate virtual machine.

Something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar",  f.getAbsolutePath());
Process p = pb.start();
```

**EDIT**

> *- Will that work if the program that does pb.start() terminates?*
>
> *- Will that work if the java environmental variable isn't set (e.g. Mac OS X?)[can't test on mac os x]*

It does. Take a look at this video:

[http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/8380/capturadepantalla201001s.png](http://www.vimeo.com/8620321)

The source code ( imports omitted ) :

```
// MainApp.java

public class MainApp {
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainApp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JLabel("<html><font size='48'>Main App Running</font><html>") );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
        launchSeparateProcess();
        frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ){
                System.out.println("MainAppp finished");
            }
        });
    }
    private static void launchSeparateProcess() throws IOException {
        File f = new File("./yourjar.jar");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", f.getAbsolutePath() );
        Process p = pb.start();
    }
}    

//-- Updater.jar
public class Updater {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JLabel("<html><font size='78'>Updating....</font></html>"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
//--manifest.mf
Main-Class: Updater
```

Comment: will that work if the program that does pb.start() terminates?

Comment: Will that work if the java environmental variable isn't set (e.g. Mac OS X?)[can't test on mac os x]